# add typings to javascript project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm using closure library, but vscode doesn't understand the goog.require statements so intellisense is kind of useless.
I found typings at https://github.com/teppeis/closure-library.d.ts, and this works if I add a ///  comment to the top of the file.
But it's going to get really annoying to add this to every single file in my project. Is there some way I can configure vscode to automatically reference this for all the javascript files in the project?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a [jsconfig.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) at the root of your workspace:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  }, 
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

This creates a project that will include any `.js` and `.d.ts` files in your workspace. You can also explicitly manage which files are part of a project using the `files` or `include` `jsconfig` options: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: That didn't make any difference. I still have to add a reference comment to the .d.ts file for intellisense to start working.